# Can someone suggest a recent survey on product form Markov chains?

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, queueing-theory, model-checking

I'm especially interested in their use in model checking applications.  I have Open, Closed and Mixed Networks of Queues with Different Classes of Customers by Baskett et al.  Any other suggestions for reading material?  Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you have in mind? Sampling or search applications?

Comment: sorry, you've said model checking. I don't know much about that stuff, so I don't know which complexity metric is more important. It seems to me that for probabilistic model checking you need to know the stationary distribution, so maybe a survey on mixing times could be more useful.

Comment: What are the types of tasks interesting with HMM for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [this](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/RWG/book.html) unpublished book by Aldous and Fill, two experts in the field. You'll find walks on product of chains there.